# Upgrade virtualbox to 5.0.16

Tags: upgrade, virtualbox

I have virtual box 5.0.14 on my Ubuntu with extension Pack 5.0.16 which makes virtual box stop working. how do I upgrade my VB to latest version? I followed instruction in the screen shot but there are some errors. when I add Virtual box repository via the second command nothing just happens. then I run the Oracle Public Key downloading command (third one in the picture) it returns this: no valid OpenPGP data found. I run "sudo apt-get install dkms" and it says dkms is already the newest version.
what am I missing here?
[image: 1]]

Actually I want to upgrade VB rather downgrading the Extension pack. I looked at the official website, it says I have to add a source to my source list but when I add the line in terminal I get this.
[image: 2]]

I even tried to add it form the software center but it didn't work. obviously there is a way to install the latest version, isn't it? why is this getting so mixed up?!!

Comment: You can uninstall the incorrect versioned extension pack rather than upgrade virtualbox itself. Would this be useful? If so put the results of this command in your question: `vboxmanage list extpacks`

Comment: Please post the output of terminal commands as text rather than a screenshot. In your case we can't e.g. see whether the pipe you added the key to `apt-key`  was correct.

Comment: thanks or your answer. I edited my question, please read it again. thanks.

Comment: The add software belongs in the Software sources.
In software center go to edit chose Software sources  pick the 2. tab and add the line to the PPA!

Answer (score 3):

There are 2 methods to get around this issue:

1. Upgrade VirtualBox
2. Remove the problematic Extension Pack

**1. Upgrade VirtualBox**

Several ways to do this but for a pure commandline method try the following; first adding repository details for Wily Werewolf (copying and pasting one line at a time):

```
echo "deb http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian wily contrib" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list
wget -q https://www.virtualbox.org/download/oracle_vbox.asc -O- | sudo apt-key add -
sudo apt-get update
```

Then install some support files and then  VirtualBox itself:

```
sudo apt-get install dkms
sudo apt-get install virtualbox-5.0
```

And on my Wily installation this gets the latest version:

[image]

**2. Remove the problematic Extension Pack**

Rather than install a greater version of VirtualBox, as demonstrated in poin t) you could simply remove the offending extension pack. On my own system:  first list the Extension Packs installed:

```
andrew@ilium~$ vboxmanage list extpacks
Extension Packs: 1
Pack no. 0:   Oracle VM VirtualBox Extension Pack
Version:      5.0.8
Revision:     103449
Edition:      
Description:  USB 2.0 and USB 3.0 Host Controller, Host Webcam, VirtualBox RDP, PXE ROM, Disk Encryption.
VRDE Module:  VBoxVRDP
Usable:       true 
Why unusable: 
andrew@ilium~$
```

The uninstall the Extension Pack:

```
andrew@ilium~$ sudo VBoxManage extpack uninstall "Oracle VM VirtualBox Extension Pack"
0%...10%...20%...30%...40%...50%...60%...70%...80%...90%...100%
Successfully uninstalled "Oracle VM VirtualBox Extension Pack".
andrew@ilium~$
```

Now VirtualBox should start...

Comment: thanks for your answer. I edited my question read it again please. now my problem is adding a source to my list. why does it say that deb command is wrong?!

Comment: @user292314 That's not a command to run - thats a line you add to the end of `/etc/apt/sources.list`... or in a separate file in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/`

Comment: OK so I beefed up my answer to cover install of the latest as well as the possibility of simply removing the renegade extension pack...